# Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:4-47:19 to override

Tags: android, flutter

estoy agregando un lector de barra pero me sale, es como si hubiera un conflicto en 2 librerias que usan la cámara

```
    Attribute application@theme value=(@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar) from [:flutter_barcode_scanner] AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-59
    is also present at [com.github.Becomedigital:become_ANDROID_SDK:2.2.4] AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-40 value=(@style/AppTheme).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:4-47:19 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@theme value=(@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar) from [:flutter_barcode_scanner] AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-59
    is also present at [com.github.Becomedigital:become_ANDROID_SDK:2.2.4] AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-40 value=(@style/AppTheme).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:4-47:19 to override.
```

me sale que hay un `'tools:replace="android:theme"'` para agregar, pero una vez agregado ocurre otro error

```
tools:replace specified at line:1 for attribute android:theme, but no new value specified
```

Como puedo solucionarlo, porque causa sale esto?

este es el `Manifest.xml`

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:replace="android:theme"
    package="com.example.money">

    ....

    android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
```

Answer (score 1):

también uso flutter_barcode_scanner a mi no me muestra este error, tengo la versión : flutter_barcode_scanner : ^1.0.1 en mi pubspec.yaml

Mi android manifest es así:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="confidencial">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application
    android:label="confidencial"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
            android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />

        <!-- Theme to apply as soon as Flutter begins rendering frames -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

Como puedes ver utilizo la implementación 2 con flutterEmbedding si no lo tienes te recomiendo actualizarlo en [Upgrading pre 1.12 Android projects](http://flutterEmbedding) esta la documentación.
No creo que sea nada de tu manifest intenta actualizar el paquete flutter_barcode_scanner, y no olvides ejecutar flutter clean despues de la actualización.

Answer (score -1):

El `tools:replace="android:theme"` debe ir en el tag del `activity` o del `application`(como te indica el error), no del manifest.

```xml
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:replace="android:theme"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        
        ...
      </activity>
```

Comment: he puesto en `manifest`, `application`, `activity`, `meta-data` y el error es el mismo, `tools:replace specified at line:1 for attribute android:theme, but no new value specified`

Comment: verifica si no tienes otro AndroidManifest.xml en tu proyecto, solo quédate con el principal